# Cannot add document on firebase cloud firestore on swift

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Newbie here on Firebase cloud firestore.

I have created a collection on cloud firestore named "push_notif" but I can't add the value from my iOS app.

When I call the function it doesn't do anything.

```
let ndb = Firestore.firestore()
self.docReference = ndb.collection("push_notif").addDocument(data: [
                            "push_id": pushID,
                            "push_type": "notification",
                            "timestamp": EndTimeStamp,
                            ], completion: { err in
                            if let err = err {
                                print("Error adding document for loser notification: \(err)")
                            } else {
                                print("Notification Document added with ID: \(String(describing: self.docReference?.documentID))")
                            }
                        })
```

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Code works perfectly for me - copied, pasted and ran. I substituted data for docReference, pushID and EndTimeStamp since that was not included.

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: It does nothing for me. I put it on a button when the button triggers it's nothing. The collection is a newly created one.

Comment: You can help us help you with some troubleshooting before posting a question. For example, add a breakpoint to this line `self.docReference = ndb..` then run your code. Does it stop at the breakpoint? No? Then the code in the question isn't running at all and the issue is *before* that code. If it does stop and you *step through your code line by line* examining your vars as you step through, what line is not giving the results you expect? Please update your question with more information and we'll take a look! In the future, respond with @Jay so I know you responded.

Comment: Okay @Jay, thank you for that. I've manage to make it work. seems like I need to get the refreshed firebase token. I had problem with just one collection the others are working but when I logout and login again the code works and saves it on the cloud firestore. Thank you for your replies. :)